# Windows Virtual Machine ping reply fails the first few times

Tags: virtual-machines, ping

I am running a windows Web Server 2008 virtual machine. When I try to ping it from another windows machine the ping reply comes straight back with 100% success. But when I try to ping it from one of the Linux boxes, the ping reply fails with partial or 100% loss the first couple of time and succeeds the third time onwards. I know it is quite strange but can any one think anything that could be causing it. Could anything in the Windows Domain Security or Firewall be "taking time" to allow responding to the ping request? In fact even the firewall is turned off on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default time out of ping on windows is 4 seconds](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490968.aspx).
[On linux its 1 second](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_ping.htm).

Comment: Thanks Serban.. that may be a clue to what is happening here.